# Convert the following cshtml to aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Need help converting the following to aspx

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.Value) : string.Empty), new { @class = "date", @style = "width:100px", maxlength = "10" })
```

I've tried the following but I'm having issues

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Nullable<DateTime>" %>
<%=Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", Model.Value) : string.Empty), new { @class = "date", @style = "width:80px", maxlength = "10" })%>
```

Comment: Show what you gave tried.

Comment: ... and what issues are you having?  Remember, we can't see your screen.

Comment: To answer the title's command: No, thanks.

Comment: `<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Nullable<DateTime>" %>` is designed for partial view. If it's a view, you must use `<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Nullable<DateTime>" %>`.